# VHDL - Inferred Latch With Reset - FSM

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I have an issue with this process where if I include a reset statement, I get an inferred latch. However, if I do not include the reset statement, I do not get an inferred latch on duty_cycle_triangle.

```
    SIGNAL duty_cycle_triangle : INTEGER := 0;
    SIGNAL count_up : STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL tick_zero : STD_LOGIC;

    triangle_count: PROCESS(clk, reset signal, tick_zero)
        BEGIN
            IF (reset = '1') THEN
                duty_cycle_triangle <= 0;
            ELSIF (RISING_EDGE(clk)) THEN
                IF (tick_zero = '1') THEN
                    IF (count_up = '1') THEN
                        duty_cycle_triangle <= duty_cycle_triangle + 2;
                    ELSE
                        duty_cycle_triangle <= duty_cycle_triangle - 2;
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
    END PROCESS;
```

I am trying to design an FSM that will output a triangle wave using a PWM and an FSM shown below:

```
        FSM_comb: PROCESS(currentState, duty_cycle_triangle)
        BEGIN
            CASE currentState IS
                WHEN triangle_up =>
                    PWM_enable <= '1';
                    count_up <= '1';
                    IF (duty_cycle_triangle > 99) THEN
                        nextState <= triangle_down;
                    ELSE
                        nextState <= triangle_up;
                    END IF;
                WHEN triangle_down =>
                    PWM_enable <= '1';
                    count_up <= '0';
                    IF (duty_cycle_triangle < 1) THEN
                        nextState <= triangle_up;
                    ELSE
                        nextState <= triangle_down;
                    END IF;
            END CASE;
    END PROCESS;


    FSM_seq: PROCESS(clk, reset)
        BEGIN
            IF (reset = '1') THEN
                currentState <= triangle_up;
            ELSIF (RISING_EDGE(clk)) THEN
                currentState <= nextState;
            END IF;
    END PROCESS FSM_seq;
```

Basically, after every "tick" I want the duty cycle of the triangle wave to increase by 2. After the duty cycle reaches 100, I want the duty cycle to decrease by 2 until the duty cycle reaches 0. Once the duty cycle reaches 0, I want the duty cycle to start increasing from 0 again until it reaches 100 and it starts over.

Does anyone see any problems with my code or can anyone point me in the right direction to correcting any issues?

Comment: Your sensivity list should only contain reset and clk for the TRIANGLE_COUNT process

Answer (score -1):

Would be nice to see where the latch is inferred, but my guess would be:
In the IF (tick_zero = '1') THEN statement.

You don't have an else assignment, look into in the a RTL viewer and you'll see.
You wrote that if tick_zero is HIGH increment my duty_cycle_triangle, but what happens if tick_zero is not high? => The tool inferres a latch to keep the current value because you haven't designed anything else what should happen with this signal.

There are a few things if this is the whole code.
First: always add the others part in case assignments. Just in the case where you are sure you managed all possibilities you can leave it away, but it doesn't hurt. We don't see your FSM states, but I guess it is a 1 bit FSM state so your inferred latch shouldn't come from this.

Like po.pe wrote, making the FSM_comp process clock synchron would do your synthesis tool a favor and shouldn't change your output, because all the signals which change something like current_state duty_cycle_triangle and so on, are already clock synchron.

Answer (score -1):

Think of it this way

In a process the actual new value of any signal is only assigned when the process is complete.

The process starts when something on the sensitivity list changes and ends at the 'end process' statement.  At this point, all the signals are assigned at exactly the same instant, even if a signal is assigned multiple times within a process it only gets the value of the last assignment.

So follow each signal through, and ask yourself if is it always assigned in all circumstances?

Latches are inferred in VHDL if at the end of a process a signal has not been assigned a new value, it has no choice but to use whatever value it last had, hence the latch.

Effectively what it is doing is adding an invisible line of code just below the clock edge statement for ALL signals assigned in the process.

```
....
ELSIF RISING_EDGE(clk) THEN
    duty_cycle_triangle <= duty_cycle_triangle;  --The future value is the same as the past (i.e. a latch)
    ...
```

Indeed you can hide the inferred latch warning by putting exactly that line in.

BTW:

1. You don't need the brackets for ifs, this is not C.
2. PWM_enable may also be inferring latches and is only ever assigned a value of '1'

Comment: `"In a process the actual new value of any signal is only assigned when the process is complete."`
While this is true for synthesizable RTL code - it is a coincidence of RTL code.   For testbenches, it is important to understand the VHDL rule.   Signals without a delay are scheduled to be updated on the next simulation cycle.   For a signal to update a process must suspend.   A process suspends when it encounters a wait statement (common to have multiple of these in a testbench) or when it exits and encounters a sensitivity list.